# ¿Como puedo hacer que cuando recorra un array i se quede en esa posicion mientras recorre todo el array j?

Tags: java, array, archivo, eclipse

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de BufferedReader donde tengo 2 ficheros

dni.txt que contiene

```
80050656F,6014394C,85614315N,80050656F,1234F
```

y personas.txt que contiene

```
19743479A;Teresa Luján
85614315N;Antonio Pérez
75998675M;Tristán Barros
80050656F;Judith Rodrigo
```

Mi codigo es este:

```
package ej2;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Objects;

public class PruebaDni {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String ruta1 = "D:\\Perfil Enrique\\Desktop\\DAM\\Programacion\\Eclipse\\EnriqueVazquezBustos\\dni";

        File f1 = new File(ruta1);

        String ruta2 = "D:\\Perfil Enrique\\Desktop\\DAM\\Programacion\\Eclipse\\EnriqueVazquezBustos\\personas";

        File f2= new File(ruta2);

        if (!f1.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("El fichero del DNI no EXISTE");

        }
        if (!f2.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("El fichero PERSONAS no EXISTE");
        }


        BufferedReader dni = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1));
        BufferedReader personas = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f2));

        int cnt = 0;

        try {
            String linea;
            String linea2;

            while ((linea = personas.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] persona = linea.split("[,;]");

                for (int i = 0; i < persona.length; i = i + 2) {
                    while ((linea2 = dni.readLine()) != null) {
                        String[] dnis = linea2.split("[,]");

                        for (int j = 0; j < dnis.length; j++) {
                            System.out.println(dnis[j]);
                            System.out.println(persona[i] + " " + cnt);
                            cnt++;

                            if (Objects.equals(dnis[j], persona[i])) {
                                System.out.println("Esta");
                            } else {
                                System.out.println("No esta");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
    }
}
```

Mi duda es que como podría hacer que el array dnis[j] busque en todo el array personas [i] o viceversa, para buscar si hay un mismo dni que esté en la lista, ya que si lo ejecutas te dice que no está porqué cuando lo ejecutas sale asi:

```
80050656F
19743479A 0
No esta
6014394C
19743479A 1
No esta
85614315N
19743479A 2
No esta
80050656F
19743479A 3
No esta
1234F
19743479A 4
No esta
```

¿Como podría hacer para que itere en 1 solo y hasta que no haya terminado pase al siguiente y que me funcione?
Al final el resultado tiene que decirme si:
**Existe el dni en la ficha persona,
si está repetido,
si no existe,
si no es un dni**

Probé con hacer contadores manuales y haciendo do while pero no me funcionaba (no tengo el código).

Muchas grácias y un saludo, es mi primer post en stack overflow y no sé si me he explicado.

**Notas: En el **for i** la i se suma +2 por qué como personas.txt tiene nombre hago un split haciendo que cada posición par sea un numero de dni.**

Answer (score 1):

lo que adjuntas demuestra que tu array `personas` solo esta guardando un valor `19743479A` el cual es distinto a cualquier otro valor de `dnis`,lo que estas generando son varios array con 2 valores `[19743479A;Teresa Luján]` como solo se necesita el valor de indice 0

lo que podrias realizar es usar un `ArrayList`  para usar el método [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) e ir iterando los valores del array `dnis`

para saber los duplicados un método que cuente las ocurrencias de un dni en el array dnis facilitaría las cosas de ser la ocurrencia > 1,sabrás que ese dni esta duplicado

```
     public static int ocurrencias(String dni,String[]arreglo){
      int cont=0;
      for (int i=0;i<arreglo.length ;i++ ) {
         if(arreglo[i].equals(dni))
            cont++;
      }return cont;
    }
 

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String ruta1 = "dni.txt";

        File f1 = new File(ruta1);

        String ruta2 = "personas.txt";

        File f2= new File(ruta2);

        if (!f1.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("El fichero del DNI no EXISTE");

        }
        if (!f2.exists()) {
            throw new FileNotFoundException("El fichero PERSONAS no EXISTE");
        }

        BufferedReader dni = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f1));
        BufferedReader personas = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(f2));

        int cnt = 0;
//Declaramos el arraylist de tipo String
        ArrayList<String>arr=new ArrayList<>();
    

        try {
            String linea;
            String linea2;

            while ((linea = personas.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] persona = linea.split(";");
//Agregamos los valores de la posicion [0]
                arr.add(persona[0]);
            }

            System.out.println("el array "+arr);
            
            while ((linea2 = dni.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] dnis = linea2.split("[,]");
                       for (int j = 0; j < dnis.length; j++) {
                        System.out.print(dnis[j]);
//si el arraylist contiene el dni y aparece mas de una vez lanzaremos duplicado
                            if (arr.contains(dnis[j])&&ocurrencias(dnis[j],dnis)>1) {
                                System.out.println("     Duplicado");
                                
                            } 
//si el array solo contiene el dni lanzaremos esta caso contrario no esta
                            else if(arr.contains(dnis[j])){
                                System.out.println("     Esta"); 
                             } 

                            else {
                                 System.out.println("      No esta");
                            }
                       } 
                }           
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]